# Vue pattern avoiding circular dependency: use of models (class modules) in Vuex store and components and store in models?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

Can anyone point to a pattern that would allow:

1. Use of models (in form of class modules) in Vuex store AND
2. Use of Vuex store in those models AND
3. Use of the models also in components?

I am able to achieve the first 2 points, but when I try to import models to any component a circular dependency occurs and application fails.

My current pattern looks like this:

*** main.js ***

```
 import { store } from 'pathToStore/store';
 export const vue = new Vue({ 
    el: '#app',
    store,
    render: h => h(App)
 });
```

*** store.js ***

```
import vuexModule from './modules/vuexModule'
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: { vuexModule }
});
```

*** vuexModule.js ***

```
import { models } from 'pathToModels/models';
export default {
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
    getters
};
```

*** models.js ***

```
import * as importedModels from './modelsAggregator';
export const models = importedModels;
```

*** modelsAggregator.js ***

```
export { MyModel} from './MyModel';
export { MyModel2} from './MyModel2';
...
```

**** MyModel.js ****

```
import { store } from 'pathToStore/store';
export class MyModel {
    constructor () {};
}
```

As I said I am able to use `models` in `store` and `store` in `models` without the circular dependency (thanks to the modelsAggregator pattern), but it would be convenient to be able to use `models` also in components. Can it be achieved?

Comment: You can't import a module in a component. You can simply dispatch action or commit mutations. If you want to import it to get data, use mapState and mapGetters.

Comment: You can't? Why not? I am importing some utility functions (like date formatter) and it works. I don't want to store any data in that imports. That is all handled by Vuex.

Comment: Because vuex modules work in vuex store, not in component individually. You can reach all modules actions by using this.$store.dispatch("moduleNameIfNameSpaced/actionName"). So you don't need to import anything to use them, since they are already part of your app.

Comment: I understand that. Maybe I didn't explain clearly enough what I'm trying to do - I want to be able to import to components class definitions that are not a part of Vuex as such, but are used in Vuex for operating on data in state (eg. new object instance to be stored in Vuex).

Answer (score 0):

It seems I found a way to pass models into components. I simply assigned the `models` object to `state` property of a vuex module. This way I have access to the models in components via `this.$store.state.models`. These are changes to the pattern described in my question:

*** store.js ***

```
import vuexModule from './modules/vuexModule';
import vuexModels from './modules/vuexModels';
export const store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: { vuexModule, models: vuexModels }
});
```

*** vuexModels.js ***

```
import { models } from 'pathToModels/models';
const state = models;
export default { state };
```

It is also important to import `store` in the entry file before the `App.vue`.